# Nexus connection not happening from jenkins Nexus Platform plugin 3.x

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I want to integrate jenkins(2.157) with nexus for uploading / downloading artifacts and using Nexus Platform plugin with version 3.3.20190108-134259.b70ae43. When trying to connect to nexus repository manager(3.7) from jenkins using uname and password, its not connecting, resulting in error - Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection failed.

Gone through similar issues in stackoverflow and jenkins support but no luck.

Expecting Test Connection should be success as a first step when connecting from jenkins.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phT0W.png)

Comment: What does it show when you click `show details`? What URL are you using? Can you access that URL using a browser from your machine? Can you access that URL from jenkins (using web browser / curl / telnet)?

Comment: @Dawid 
Below is the error inside show details

`Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection failed
com.sonatype.nexus.api.di: service/rest/wonderland/status
 at com.sonatype.nexus.api.dj.handleResponse(SourceFile:51)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:223)`.

The URL belongs to our organisation **https://aaa.sample.com/nexus**

Yes I can able to access the url from my machine.

Comment: Anything in the nexus.log at a the same time?